# flask try except не работает

Tags: python, flask, request, try

Делаю сервер на Flask и столкнулся с проблемой.
Код

```
@app.route('/tes')
def test():
    try:
        a = 1/0
        return jsonify('ok')
    except Exception as error:
        return jsonify(error)
```

не работает. Как мне когда происходит ошибка через jsonify отправлять уведомление об ошибке?

Answer (score 1):

оказывается, что JSON принимает узкий круг данных, поэтому когда вы посылаете Exception он ругается на это. Чтобы это пофиксить используйте

```
return jsonify(f"{error}")
```

а в полном коде это выглядит как

```
@app.route('/tes')
def test():
    try:
        a = 1/0
        return jsonify('test')
    except Exception as error:
        print(type(error))
        return jsonify(f"{error}")
```